# MAUI .NET 8 - SocketsHttpHandler+HttpClient - Different behaviour Windows vs Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui

Hi to all (first time asking, so be kind ;P ).
I'm writing an app in MAUI with .NET 8. This app should just make a Get request to an URI and expose the response.
It's involved an X509Certificate2 but that works just fine.
This is the piece of code giving me problems:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), _uriAddress))
    {
        ResponseArea.Text += "HTTP request: ";
        ResponseArea.Text += "[" + request.RequestUri + "]" + Environment.NewLine;
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ResponseArea.Text += "---- RESPONSE ----" + Environment.NewLine;
 
        //DO SOME STUFF WITH THE JSON RESPONSE
    }
    ResponseArea.Text += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "---- FINE RESPONSE ----";
}
```

When I run the app on Windows machine it works correctly, get the response and shows it in the text property of the xaml element in the view.

But when compiled and run for Android (13.0 Android - API 33) with the emulator of VS2022 and also on my phone, it get stuck awaiting the response.

Before I was using the HttpClientHandler but since MS suggest to use Socket instead, so I did (and also I was having problems with the ClientCertificates property of the handler, which on Android isn't initialized and was causing a null reference when adding the X509).

As you can see in the first screenshot, it get stuck on the SendAsync call.
As you can see in the second screenshot, it works just fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iWrt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NjCQ.png)

Since on windows actually works correctly I think is some kind o different behavior like the HttpClientHandler or some missing setting I should do for Android platforms. But I can't understand what's going on.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I run the same code on Windows and Android.
Expected to get the same results and behaviour.
Instead get stuck on the SendAsync on Android platform.

Also tried different API but get the same results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWm6I.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQLTC.png)

Edit: added 2 screenshots. Same code on win and android. No error messages or events. On Android the app just keeps waiting for the responde that never comes (apparently). It happens on the emulator and on my phone. As you can see I added a messagge right after the response variable get a value. On windows it works. On Android it just stays there.

Edit: probably it's a problem on how I manage the certificate, because a simple call to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ works on both windows and android. So I'm gonna try to understand why this happens.

Comment: Could you please post the full error log about this problem?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding!
Actually there's no error log. When run on Android it just stays awaiting for the response. But I'll try to put as much as dubug info as possibile. Just out of curiosity: do you get the same problem? Because if not, is surely something I'm missing. For now thank you again and I'll update as soon as possibile!

Comment: Added screenshots!

Comment: Have you used the [Task-based asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) for your data request?

Comment: I did what it's in the code. But i found a good tutorial on the httpclient and probably I did some mistakes. I'll try a refactor and let you know!

Comment: Waiting for your good news.  :)

Comment: Sorry... no good news... apparently there's no solution to this :(

Comment: What have you tried? And could you please post the latest code?

Comment: I tried what's in the code up there. But didn't work. Anyway I got busy on another project so I think I'll close soon this post since it seems impossible to resolve. Thanks for your time and happy xmas